# What happens to the Django admin site during production?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, security

Django offers an admin interface at `/admin`. Is it not safe to keep this URL during production?

Or should I change the URL to `/d0oai32492384h24ui234nij23n4k2jnkjnkjn` or something?

Comment: Why do you think it's not safe on production exactly ?

Comment: The fact that superuser access can be made so easily - and I don't assume big websites like twitter or facebook would have them.

Comment: Well, even if someone goes to that url he will just get a form with login and password that must be passed to access an admin interface. Also he must be superuser to do that which means he had to be created via: "python3 manage.py createsuperuser" on your production server/

Comment: @Madi7 seems to be right but most people suggest using a different url than /admin only for the reason to make it tough to find the admin panel as if anybody finds that he can easily try brute force increasing the inbound traffic and in case successful app is compromised. If possible also try restricting /admin or equivalent to internal network only or to some IPs only.

Comment: I think admin site is pretty secure. If you want to change `/admin/` the default endpoint of admin site, you can do it on `urls.py`.... `url(r'^some_other_endpoint/', admin.site.urls),`

Comment: A useful blog post: https://opensource.com/article/18/1/10-tips-making-django-admin-more-secure

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want (this won't work on Django < 2.0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('d0oai32492384h24ui234nij23n4k2jnkjnkjn/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This will work on Django < 2.0:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^d0oai32492384h24ui234nij23n4k2jnkjnkjn/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This has to be done in your main urls.py file.
You can access it by typing:

```
http://localhost:8000/d0oai32492384h24ui234nij23n4k2jnkjnkjn/
```